# how do I dynamically create URLs in Twig with Parameters

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am trying to create a list of links to use as filters for a page.

but struggling with understanding the twig way.

For example, I have many facets which all have many elements stored in an array, for example facet maybe country one of many elements for country is France.

I have the following code so far, ????? shows where I am lost as to how to define

```
{% for name, facet in facets %}
{% for element in facet %}
<a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), {?????, ?????}) }}">{{ facetTags[name]['display_name'] }}</a>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Every logical approach I can think of leads to errors.

Comment: What exactly should the question marks hold?

Answer (score 0):

```html
 {% for Element in array %}
<a href ="{{ path('root_1', {'idElement':Element.idElelment}) }}">{{'idElement':Element.idElelment}}</a>

 {%endfor%}
```

This URL gonna send to the root_1 the selected idElement, the first one {'idElement':Element.idElelment} is for the value that gonna be send to the root_1 and  the last one is for what gonna be display and if you are changed the return value of the __toString() methode  (For exemple in this case the __toString methode doesn't get back the Element's Id ) you must use Element.idElelment.idElement  .